# Convert from String to the most suitable datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection

I am trying to build a dynamic Web API that calls existing methods using

`GetMethod(String methodName, Type[] Types)`

in `System.Reflection`. Due to polymorphism, the naive approach, using `GetMethod(String methodName)` fails when methods with the same names are called.

This is what my dynamic Web API main method header looks like:

```
public Object API_GET(HttpRequestMessage request)
```

I read the contents of the `request` like this:

```
    var content = request.Content;
    string contentString = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

The string `contentString` is now structured like this:

```
"command='aCommand'&param1=1&param2='nnn'" // example
```

Now I would like to know how I can use `GetMethod(methodName, Types)` to call the appropriate existing method based on the parameters extracted from the string above

Is there a way in C# to convert a string to the most suitable datatype?

e.g.

```
"2"    => Int
"2.0"  => Double
"true" => Bool
"nnn"  => String
```

Comment: I think you simply have to use Some TryParse funtionality to convert value on bases of type

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do what you want, but it is not hard to write a series of parsers to try your combinations and return the first one that succeeds. The only downside to this is because you can't know which parser succeeded ahead of time the type that is returned will be `object`, but you can use the [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to test the result to find out which type it is.

```
public static class GenericParser
{
    //create a delegate which our parsers will use 
    private delegate bool Parser(string source, out object result);

    //This is the list of our parsers
    private static readonly List<Parser> Parsers = new List<Parser>
    {
        new Parser(ParseInt),
        new Parser(ParseDouble),
        new Parser(ParseBool),
        new Parser(ParseString)
    };

    public static object Parse(string source)
    {
        object result;
        foreach (Parser parser in Parsers)
        {
            //return the result if the parser succeeded.
            if (parser(source, out result))
                return result;
        }

        //return null if all of the parsers failed (should never happen because the string->string parser can't fail.)
        return null;
    }

    private static bool ParseInt(string source, out object result)
    {
        int tmp;
        bool success = int.TryParse(source, out tmp);
        result = tmp;
        return success;
    }

    private static bool ParseDouble(string source, out object result)
    {
        double tmp;
        bool success = double.TryParse(source, out tmp);
        result = tmp;
        return success;
    }

    private static bool ParseBool(string source, out object result)
    {
        bool tmp;
        bool success = bool.TryParse(source, out tmp);
        result = tmp;
        return success;
    }

    private static bool ParseString(string source, out object result)
    {
        result = source;
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Here is a test program](http://ideone.com/r0kEJc)

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestString("2");
        TestString("2.0");
        TestString("true");
        TestString("nnn");
    }

    static void TestString(string testString)
    {
        object result = GenericParser.Parse(testString);
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"\t => {1}", testString, result.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Its output:

```
"2"      => Int32
"2.0"    => Double
"true"   => Boolean
"nnn"    => String
```

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic type, it will automatically convert your type.
e.g

```
    dynamic v1 = 0;
    v1 = 5;
```